# footer-html and footer-right should be shown together - wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I want a footer which is defined in the html page and page number in the footer-right.

Footer-html and footer-right both are shown. But footer-right is in invisible font.

Is there anything like, when footer-html is shown, other footer attributes are not taken into consideration?

Comment: It seems that it's not possible, take a look of this [footer and header htmls with page number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174359/how-to-do-page-numbering-in-header-footer-htmls-with-wkhtmltopdf)