# wkhtmltopdf - Generate document index

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to create an user manual from an html source. I already managed to number the pages thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174359/how-to-do-page-numbering-in-header-footer-htmls-with-wkhtmltopdf).

Now I wonder if there is any way to auto generate a document index based on the header tags on the html source.

For instance, if I have this:

```
<h1>Cars</h1>                   (page 3)
   <p>blah blah blah</p>
   <h2>Peugeot</h2>             (page 3)
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
   <h2>Renault</h2>             (page 4)
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
<h1>Supermarkets</h1>           (page 5)
   <p>blah blah blah</p>
   <h2>Walmart</h2>             (page 7)
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
   <h2>Carrefour</h2>           (page 11)
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
```

I would like to have an auto-generated document index that looks like this:

```
User Manual Index

Cars.......................3
  Peugeot..................3
  Renault..................4
Supermarkets...............5
  Walmart..................7
  Carrefour................11
```

Is it possible to achieve it using wkhtmltopdf / JavaScript ?
At least could you please advice me where to start?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would take a look at the table of contents options available to wkhtmltopdf via http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt toc options.