# How to use page number in thead?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want use page number in thead. I use this code:

```
@media print {
body { margin: 0; }
thead { counter-reset: pages; }
.page-number:before { counter-increment: pages; content: " "; }
.page-number:after { counter-increment: page; }
.page-number:after { content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages); }
}
```

But this not working in chrome.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KeuwU/8/)

Comment: I think chrome has some limitations, do you strictly want to stay on the CSS part? because you can use javascript as well to dynamically add page number.

Comment: @moazahmad: I have no problem with any trick that can solve my need.

Comment: Seems to work ok on your fiddle in Chrome 114.0.5735.199 on Windows.

Comment: @freedomn-m: I use the same version, but when printing, 'Page 1 of 1' is displayed on all pages

Comment: it could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402991/how-to-use-css-counter-increment-for-dynamic-page-numbers

Comment: ...and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174359/how-to-do-page-numbering-in-header-footer-htmls-with-wkhtmltopdf/13496899#13496899

Comment: @sylvain: The first link you sent is the demo of my question

Comment: @sylvain: The second method also does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="page-number"></div>
      </th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
...
</table>
```

```css
@media print {

  thead {
    counter-reset: pages;
  }

  .page-number:before {
    counter-increment: pages;
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

Or using javascript:

```js
 <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var pageNumbers = document.getElementsByClassName('page-number');
      var pageCount = pageNumbers.length;
      
      for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
        pageNumbers[i].textContent = 'Page ' + (i + 1) + ' of ' + pageCount;
      }
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: If you test the proposed method, you will see that it shows the number 1 on all pages. I tested many of the suggested methods on the site, but all of them do not work in the latest versions of the Chrome browser.